# Linking a class member's type to an external URL in doxygen

Tags: c#, class, doxygen, member, external-url

I'm using doxygen to write the documentation for a C# codebase. Some of the classes I'm working with include member variables whose types are external to the code, and these external types already have extensive documentation in the form of web pages; I would naturally like to link to those pages in the generated documentation.

If, for example, one class has a member of type Foo, and Foo belongs to my codebase, doxygen correctly generates a link to that class within my documentation when generating the "Public Attributes" section for the class.

But if another class has a member of type Bar, and Bar does not belong to my codebase but does have a web page dedicated to it at http://someURL.com/Bar.html, I seem to have no way of turning the type of the member in the "Public Attributes" section into a link to that page.

Anyway I can accomplish that? This question is extensive to the type of method parameters which are also external to my codebase, I would love to be able to turn their type names into appropriate links in the generated documentation. Ditto for properties, return values, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Update: I'm using doxygen 1.8.3.1